# ViewPager and PageTransformer

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-animation

How can I update the incoming view in a ViewPager while dragging and using a custom PageTransformer?
By default , the ViewPager update the next view while dragging but when I write a custom PageTransformer it won't render until the whole view is ready and before that it is just a grey page.

Comment: Check [actionbarViewPager](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppuv-FP6c4w)

Comment: Thx dude but the default animation of ViewPager working fine as well. I want to learn how to implement my PageTransformer with this feature.